# JQuery Animate scroll down to the bottom of a long list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, jquery-pagination

I have a page like this and use jquery pageless for pagination. Now, I need to run a script to scroll down to the bottom. I tried jquery animate in a loop but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="main-con">
<div class="items-list">
    <h3 class="title">1000000 items</h3>
    <div class="item" item-id="1">            
        <div class="item-button"></div>
    </div>
    ...........
    <div class="item" item-id="1000000">            
        <div class="item-button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="load-more"><span>Loading more..</span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var total_items = 1000000 ;
var count_per_page = 30 ;
var max_id = 30;
$(document).ready(function(){
  init_pageless(total_items/count_per_page)
})
function init_pageless(total)
{
  $('.main-con').pageless({
    totalPages: total,
    currentPage: 1,
      url: $(location).attr('href'),
      loader: $("#load-more"),
      params: {
        max_id: max_id ,
        },
      inited: false,
      scrape: function(data) {
        $('.items-list').append(data.html);
        this.params.max_id = data.max_id;
      }
    })

}
</script>
</div>
```

And I run this script to continuously scroll down the page for me, it seems ok at first, but it gets slow down more and more after each animation.

```
function loadmore() {$("html, body").animate(
   { scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() }, 100, loadmore);
}; 
loadmore();
```